# Accidentally cleared all browsing data in Edge, how to recover passwords having a synced account?

Tags: passwords, microsoft-edge

I have a synced account om Microsoft Edge where all my passwords are stored. I've accidentally removed all browser data including passwords.

Is there a (general) not OS-dependent way to recover this (as Edge is available multi-platform)? I hope Microsoft automatically makes a backup of my passwords which I can restore.

Any solution?

localappdata on windows, nothing there
I hope microsoft makes automatic backups/snapshots

Comment: Hi @bloc ky, have you tried my solution? If it does not work for you, we can try to find whether there's another one that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Edge Passwords are stored in a file called `Login Data` under your profile folder. If you are lucky enough, you can restore them. Here're some steps:

1. Close your Edge browser and go to your profile folder. If you are not sure about it, you can check it in `edge://version`. Normally it should be `C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\ProfileName`, but in this step we need to return to its parent folder which is `User Data`.
2. Under that folder you'll find a folder called `Snapshots`. Under `Snapshots` folder you'll see several sub-folders named with version number. You can go to folder with the most recent version number.
3. Then, you should have a sub-folder named with your **profile name** (the same name as what you have in `Profile path` in `edge://version`), such as `Profile 1`.
4. Open that folder and copy `Login Data` file. Then, paste it into your profile folder and replace the original one.

After all these steps, you should have those restored passwords. If it fails, you can try other `Login Data` file in the `Snapshots` folder, but just make sure it matches your profile.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to just add that your device should be totally offline (no WiFi or Ethernet cable). If it is online, your edge will always clear the passwords and revert back to last synced data (when you cleared passwords).